# Choosing reasonable priors for Poisson GLMM

Tags: bayesian, glmm, prior, poisson-regression, uninformative-prior

I am using the package `brms` in R to fit a generalized linear mixed model using a Poisson distribution with log link.

The model takes count data that ranges from 0 to 3 as response variable, and two z-transformed (standardized) continuous predictors and their interaction as fixed effects.

I wanted to use a prior for the fixed effects that does not give importance to completely implausible values for the coefficients. For example, if this was a linear model, I would set the prior for all fixed effects as a normal distribution with `mean = 0` and `sd = 1.5`, meaning that I am 95% certain that a one standard-deviation increase/decrease in the predictors will not be associated to more than a 3-unit increase/decrease in the response variable — after all, this is the entire range of my response variable!

I am having a hard time applying the same reasoning to a Poisson model, because a one-unit increase in the predictor is associated to a multiplicative (not additive) change in the response variable. Following the line of thought above, absolutely any value would be plausible, from minus infinity ($ln(0/3) = -\infty$) to infinity ($ln(3/0) = \infty$).

My question is: how can I choose a reasonable prior in this case? Or do I — and, by extension, anyone fitting Poisson models with a response variable that includes zeroes — have no choice but to set a flat prior?